# Prove that $2^m$ >$2^n$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

A proof for , **$2^m$ >$2^n$**
Whenever , m > n
Where , m and n are positive integers..

By the way I have defined positive integers using inductive sets - **a real number that belongs to every inductive set is a positive integer.**

Comment: If you divide both sides by $2^n$ this is equivalent to proving that $2^{m-n}>1$ whenever $m>n$.  Let us call $m-n$ something, say $k$.  Is $2^k>1$ whenever $k$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Then i have to prove that k is a positive integer

Comment: $\log_2(2^a) = a$...

Comment: You haven't yet proven that integers are closed under addition and subtraction? Or you haven't yet proven that a positive number minus something smaller than it is still positive?

Comment: @JMoravitz I have not proven that integers are closed under addition or subtraction..the first one you listed.

Comment: @JMoravitz A binary operation on a set is closed by *definition*. Just the definition of addition and subtraction shows that the result of either is again an integer.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId i have defined these binary operations on the set of real numbers directly..not on integers..

Comment: I have now proved that 2^k > 0 for all positive integral values of k ..so the only thing now is to prove that k is a positive integer.

Comment: Yes, $x \in \mathbb{Z} \implies x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality can be written as $$2^{m-n}>1$$ but as $m>n$ thus $m-n\geq 0$ thus the power of $2$ is always positive thus its always greater than $1$ hence $2^m>2^n$

Comment: Can we prove that 2^k > 0 if k>0 from that definition which i have used

Comment: Not so true $2^{-1/2}=1/2^{1/2}=100/142\approx 0.7092...$ i think rather than $k>0$ it should be k is real

Comment: Apart from integers

Comment: For me the proof for positive integral values of "k" is sufficient i am not going into reals ...